# ESLint : Fast way to solve "Irregular whitespace not allowed"

Tags: javascript, eslint, js-beautify

I'm trying to use ESLint to enforce a coding style on a project, and I have many `Irregular whitespace not allowed` errors  caused by code like this :

```
var a = b ||  10; //note the 2 spaces between || and 10
if (a === 10)  {  // again, 2 spaces between ) and {
```

I haven't found any way to solve this problem easily for all my files.
I think basic regex wouldn't work, as double spaces can be valid in some situations (column indentation of JSON object, indentation with soft tabs, strings).

I tried tools, such as js-beautify, but didn't find any options to solve this problem. Is there a tool that could help me ?

Comment: when i paste your code into http://danml.com/slim/ and click Tools > Beautify, it removes the extra space.

Comment: I should have specified I'm looking for a command line tool

Comment: What eslint rule are you using?

Comment: well the beautify part is a small js routine, i'm sure it can run in node if need be...

Comment: Do you want the two spaces or do you want the extra spaces removed.  js-beautify should remove those spaces automatically.  No options needed.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the extension [fix-irregular-whitspace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=karlito40.fix-irregular-whitespace) for **vscode**

It works by replacing **all non breaking space** from your code with a **normal space**.

### Features

- Automatically replace non breaking space **at save time**.
- Add a "Fix irregular whitespace **in current file**" command to replace all non breaking space at will.
- Add a "Fix irregular whitespace **in workspace**" command to replace all non breaking space inside a workspace. (It will rewrite and save your file not currently open in your editor and just update the active ones without saving them).

### Install

[image]

### How to run

Command pallet (**CTRL + SHIFT + P**) and:

```
> Fix irregular whitespace in workspace
```

for whole workspace (project, folder)

[image]

```
> Fix irregular whitespace in current file
```

For the current file!

Once executed ! The whole run in the background!

Once the command run and finish! You get this notification!

[image]

**If you are not using vscode**! Then you can use it by using vscode! You can easily open your project folder with vscode! Install the extension! And running the command simply ! And magic done!

I use vscode for many things even when i'm working with othe IDE (like code block once (i had to ! Helping a friend!))!

Vscode is so powerful! In many ways!

### What are irregular spaces

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-irregular-whitespace

A sort of like invalid whitespace that is not a **normal tab and space**. Some of these characters may cause issues in modern browsers and others will be a debugging issue to spot. (I had a bad experience once where i scratched my head over all! In the end i was lucky i used a certain editor that spot the bad white space for me! And it was the reason)!

Happy us eslint detect them! And so many editors and tools!

Eslint take those spaces as irregular spaces

```
\u000B - Line Tabulation (\v) - <VT>
\u000C - Form Feed (\f) - <FF>
\u00A0 - No-Break Space - <NBSP>
\u0085 - Next Line
\u1680 - Ogham Space Mark
\u180E - Mongolian Vowel Separator - <MVS>
\ufeff - Zero Width No-Break Space - <BOM>
\u2000 - En Quad
\u2001 - Em Quad
\u2002 - En Space - <ENSP>
\u2003 - Em Space - <EMSP>
\u2004 - Tree-Per-Em
\u2005 - Four-Per-Em
\u2006 - Six-Per-Em
\u2007 - Figure Space
\u2008 - Punctuation Space - <PUNCSP>
\u2009 - Thin Space
\u200A - Hair Space
\u200B - Zero Width Space - <ZWSP>
\u2028 - Line Separator
\u2029 - Paragraph Separator
\u202F - Narrow No-Break Space
\u205f - Medium Mathematical Space
\u3000 - Ideographic Space
```

An example and insight on the problems that they can cause:

> Invalid or irregular whitespace causes issues with ECMAScript 5 parsers and also makes code harder to debug in a similar nature to mixed tabs and spaces.

> Various whitespace characters can be inputted by programmers by mistake for example from copying or keyboard shortcuts. Pressing Alt + Space on macOS adds in a non breaking space character for example.

> A simple fix for this problem could be to rewrite the offending line from scratch. This might also be a problem introduced by the text editor: if rewriting the line does not fix it, try using a different editor.

**Known issues these spaces cause:**

Zero Width Space

- Is NOT considered a separator for tokens and is often parsed as an Unexpected token ILLEGAL
- Is NOT shown in modern browsers making code repository software expected to resolve the visualization

Line Separator

- Is NOT a valid character within JSON which would cause parse errors

## OK

# Ok NO

YEA what is this ok NO! You don't know!?

**There is an irregular space that i created there!**

Where it is !? Here > `#<irregular space>OK<normal space>NO`!

I typed literaly `# + ALT + SPACE + "OK NO"`! The speed is the reason! I did it fast! I know that trick! i can create this irregular space type at will!

You want to know more ! Check my article about irregular space here:

[Fixing and removing irregular spaces](https://allalmohamedlamine.medium.com/fixing-and-removing-irregular-spaces-984389e17132?sk=9ee09413890da845b6af5f680af0fbe5)

Check the **how to create them** section! It talks about the problem with **markdown**! You can see that in **stackoverflow**! **README.md** files writing! If you already had so much of that problem! Write it slow # + space and it should be ok!

Here another irregular space that i did in purpose

[image]

# + space fast! Then removing #!

In fact for that irregular space to be create we need Only `ALT + SPACE`! That's what make it!

You can see that the editor detect it (vscode here with eslint linter) !

## UPDATE (for eslint)

A fix implementation for eslint lint rule is already worked out actually! It will get out in few days! It will go as an **eslint Plugin** (npm install + add to extends) (which allow supporing old eslint version)! And then for newewer version of eslint! It may go in the core rule too! Check again soon! I'll update this section too! With full details!

You can check it in this issue if you like https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/14073

Comment: Thanks so much for this VSCode plugin! :) Saves my lifetime right now. One question: why is there no CLI tool for this? Any way to call your plugin on a path-glob from the shell? I prefer shell tools. also, why doesn't eslint --fix work like yours?

Comment: I see. I wonder. But it's easy to make a cli tool. In any language we can use a glob module. In nodejs I would use the npm glob module. Then as it was done in the extension. There isn't too much to the code. And we can add watch too if we want using chokidar. I can do that by sparing 2 to 3 hrs. I may go for it. I.ll contact u once it's done. I.ll profit and make a tuto as I.m willing to do some teaching. It would make a good material.

Comment: Also for the plugin. Thanks go to the author Karlito40.

Comment: are you saying that ESlint latest versions now auto-fixes this successfully ? :)

Comment: also, understood your point that a tool could be quickly crafted of course. but i guess in the end i would suggest this should be made part - i.e "fixed" - in/of eslint (not another devDep tool in my project plz xD)

Comment: Hi bro! I made a big mistake! I wasn't well when i first answered! And i was out of context! Sorry! No eslintt --fix doesn't work! You may see the why in this link: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/14073#issuecomment-775088802 ! Still they can implement the fix that only get used by precising the rule! Because part of the --fix all! Not always it's all right!
I'm crafting a library to be used with nodejs! It can be too flexible that way! I started yesterday! i should have finished! But then i started complicating things! But it's worth it!

Comment: Sounds great, any news? :)

Comment: I had a lot going those past days. I'll notify through may and here as soon as it's done. I.ll get to it soon.

Comment: Maybe you should just work directly with ESlint people on this? https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/14073

Comment: If it gonna be done for eslint more options should go! For instance remove them only at code level but not within strings! Which can be done through the usage of esprisma or ts-morph! Even though one need to know first how eslint works! I don't know! Have a pecial command for it or make it optional and only after activation! Disabled by default! Because it's not always wanted! And then it depends! In my own usage i don't see where i need irrgular spaces in my code! I'll finish first the module! I've been busy otherwise it should have been finished! And in the day i give it time

Comment: i went for building a module that allow easy treatement of line by line! Through streams for ability to handle big files! And there was some design decision to make there! But the part that made me not finish by that day! Was i wanted to use multithreading! Then the challenge of having a simple module and from the main thread scope setup the treating function! With it's dependencies! Was an interesting problem! i thought about something! Then i got busy after it! i'll get back to it soon! I may get a simple version first! Where i'll skip multithreading for processing!

Comment: That version i can get it out! In one day! And i'm thinking so! I like to have a separate module! Because then one can have a cli tool! That works everywhere! Plus easy scripting with nodejs in any other project! For eslint! If the team allow setting a fix for it! It would be nice! Otherwise better! We can make the rule separately! As many rules set are made! And so who want to add it! Can easily add it's support https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules
https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/
https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/contributing/new-rules

Comment: https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/05/27/writing-custom-eslint-rules
Nice article that can bring some nice elements faster! Including how eslint work in regard of a rule writing! How the Syntax abstract tree is traversed for us! And too to publish your own custom rule! An eslint plugin is needed to be created! That can be a good road! In case the fix will not be accepted by the team! One can add some options for the rule! Like excluding strings! Or even listing an Array of elements type of the Syntax Abstract tree! And it will give more flexibility! I'll see!

Comment: There is a friend that want to build a plugin that may interest her! If she doesn't take it! I'll work on it myself!

Comment: Another good resource https://astexplorer.net/ for easy working and visualization of AST 
mentioned in

For fixing

https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules#applying-fixes

Comment: Rule code source
https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/lib/rules/no-irregular-whitespace.js

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to do this on the command line, you can pipe the output of `awk` or `ts` to `tee` (if they are available on your OS). The options below will normalize the whitespace in your file, and overwrite the existing file:

*(Warning! This will overwrite the contents of `file.js`)*
**Option #1:** `tr -s " " < file.js | tee file.js`
**Option #2:** `awk '{$2=$2};1' file.js | tee file.js`

Suppose you have a `file.js` file with the following contents:

```
// there       are lots        of spaces
// in      this          file
var a    =    b     ||  10;
if (  a  ===   10     )  { 
 //      ....
}
```

After running one of the commands above, the `file.js` file will look like this:

```
// there are lots of spaces
// in this file
var a = b || 10;
if ( a === 10 ) {
// ....
}
```

If you just want to print the result of the corrected whitespace contents **to the terminal without overwriting the file**, just don't pipe the output to `tee`, like this:

**Option #1:** `tr -s " " < file.js`
**Option #2:** `awk '{$2=$2};1' file.js`

Otherwise, if you want to **output the contents to a new file**:

**Option #1:** `tr -s " " < file.js | tee newfile.js`
**Option #2:** `awk '{$2=$2};1' file.js | tee newfile.js`

**Output to a Same File**
**Option #1:** `tr -s " " < file.js | tee file.js`
**Option #2:** `awk '{$2=$2};1' file.js | tee file.js`

That being said, you should always be super cautious and conduct detailed tests before you trust command line operations on your source code files.

**Check out [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145978/replace-multiple-spaces-with-one-using-tr-only) for better details and more options.**